# Server.Transfer from ASP.NET to ASP

Tags: asp.net, http, asp-classic

No duplicate of “[Server.Transfer from ASP to ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127733/)” ;-)

On an IIS web server (running Classic ASP), I have a local URL that a user is remotely redirected to. Presumably, this call is made with data in the query string or transmitted through POST data. When this request is made, I need to remove this data (especially the query string) server-side, so none will be visible to the client.

For example, the user is led to `http://example.com/dir/?data=payload`. This is what requested, and this is what the user’s browser will display. Now I need the request resource to strip QueryString and Form data, so that the user ends up in e.g. `http://example.com/dir/`.

On MSDN, they have [HttpServerUtility.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which adds a boolean to the classic `Server.Transfer` method allowing to preserve or clear data. However, when I try this in an `aspx` file transfering to an `asp` file, I get a `0x80004005` HTTP exception (*“No http handler was found for request type 'GET'”*).

1. Is it possible at all to “redirect” from an ASP.NET file to a Classic one?
2. Is there another, better way to remove request data server-side?

Answer (score 2):

My options would be:

1. Use a redirect on the page without querystrings: `Response.Redirect()` This will clear post data as well.
2. Do a `HTTP Request` to scrape the HTML of the other page, and view it in your current page.

I would probably do option #1

Comment: It’s cool `Response.Redirect` also loses request data—I didn’t know that. Anyway, this causes another roundtrip, since the browser gets a `302 Found`. Thank you for this solution, but I’m still interested in, let’s say, an answer to question 1. ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by request data? If you're referring to referer, etc. You would need to append that either in querystrings or sessions before you do the redirect, and the redirect page should read from there. Or with option 2, you can append the request data as variables in the headers, querystring or postdata.

Comment: By “request data”, I referred to data provided in the request, i.e. GET and POST data. I couldn’t find a generic name for both. Anyway, I’m not quite getting your option #2, please exemplify.

Comment: Then what's your question about?  If you want to preserve the "request data" you would use `Server.Transfer`, if you don't want to preserve it, use `Response.Redirect`.  In regards to option #2, you can find more information how to post a HTTP Request here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885170/http-get-request-asp-im-lost